# Can my javascript function be interrupted by an animation frame

Tags: javascript, multithreading, animation, requestanimationframe

I have recently learned about requestAnimationFrame and how it can be used to schedule animation code in sync with the browser's internal draw loop. But I am still a bit unclear about how the browser handles this type of scheduling. Will it interrupt my scripts if necessary to perform animations?

Consider the following bit of javascript code:

```
function doStuff() {
  var animated = false;

  var animation = function() {
    // perform animation
    animated = true;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(animation);

  // perform more operations here

  // Q: is animated guaranteed to be false here??

}
```

I know that Javascript is essentially single-threaded so my gut feeling is that under no circumstances should `animation()` have been called already when we reach the last line of `doStuff()`. But hopefully someone here can give a more informed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, your callback won't be called until at least the call to `doStuff` has completed.

The [nascent specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/#processingmodel) for the animation stuff refers to the HTML5 spec's concept of [queuing a task](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#queue-a-task) for the window's event loop. This is the same concept used with `setTimeout` and `setInterval`, when their time has expired, and means that while the callback will be *queued* at that moment in time, the browser waits until the main JavaScript UI thread is next available before executing the next task in the queue. The same thing happens with events; the event can happen at any time, including while your JavaScript code is running, but the call to your *handler* will queue until the main UI thread is free to handle it.

---

> I know that Javascript is essentially single-threaded...

JavaScript, the language, is silent on the concept of threading. In browsers, there's one main thread that can interact with the DOM, and zero or more [web worker](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) threads which can't (they can do other things, and exchange messages with the main UI thread, which arrive as event callbacks, which are...queued as above :-) ).

Comment: Thanks, that confirms my understanding of how this stuff works.